# Calling a snowflake function with NULL arguments

Tags: sql, function, null, arguments, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Trying to invoke a Snowflake table function with a `NULL` arguments but it looks to be imposible

PoC function I'm trying to invoke

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add5_colo (n1 number, n2 number, n3 VARCHAR) 
RETURNS table( i VARCHAR)
  AS
  $$
    SELECT 'n1 + n2 + 5 + n3' AS i
  $$
  ;
```

When I call the function as

```
SELECT * FROM table(add5_colo(1, 2, NULL));
```

I get the following error

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 20 Invalid argument types for function 'ADD5_COLO': (NUMBER(1,0), NUMBER(1,0), NULL)

We've spend all day reading documentation and coding different ideas but nothing have worked yet

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to pass `NULL` as argument to function call. It has to be casted first to match expected parameter's data type:

```
 SELECT * FROM table(add5_colo(1, 2, NULL)); 
 -- error
```

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM table(add5_colo(1, 2, NULL::VARCHAR));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using ‘’ (empty string) instead of NULL for the VARCHAR parameter

BTW, i’m not sure what you want the function to do but, as written, it looks like it will return the string 'n1 + n2 + 5 + n3' every time, regardless of what your input values are